# Set values for a column in a pandas Dataframe using values from a different row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, df:

````
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'sku': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
         'date': ['2022-08-29', '2022-08-30', '2022-08-29', 
                  '2022-08-30', '2022-08-29', '2022-08-30'],
         'End': [100, 110, 0, 210, 300, 310]}) ``` 

   sku      date    End
0   A   2022-08-29  100
1   A   2022-08-30  110
2   B   2022-08-29  0
3   B   2022-08-30  210
4   C   2022-08-29  300
5   C   2022-08-30  310
````

I want today's `starting value` to be yesterday's `end value`.

So, I want to create a column 'Start' such as:
`Start = End`, for the same sku, but for the previous date's `End value` (different row).
This should apply only to the rows where there is a previous date for that sku.

The result should look like this:

```
   sku      date     End  Start
0   A   2022-08-29   100    
1   A   2022-08-30   110   100
2   B   2022-08-29   0  
3   B   2022-08-30   210    0
4   C   2022-08-29   300    
5   C   2022-08-30   310   300
```

In my real dataset, I have values for 'End' for every date (no missing values, just 0's), so this should apply to every date except the first one. The first date is the same for every sku.

I've tried iterating over the DataFrame using `for` loops, but it's inefficient and ugly.

Is there a way to do this using a pandas function like `assign` or `apply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['B']=df.groupby('sku')['A'].shift(1).fillna('')
df
```

```
    sku     date    A   B
0   A   2022-08-29  100     
1   A   2022-08-30  110     100.0
2   B   2022-08-29  0   
3   B   2022-08-30  210     0.0
4   C   2022-08-29  300     
5   C   2022-08-30  310     300.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveed! Another alternative to get the same result is using the parameter ```fill_value=''``` in ```.shift()```: ```df['B']=df.groupby('sku')['A'].shift(1, fill_value='') ```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
df['B'] = [None] + list(df['A'].values)[:df.shape[0]-1]
```

output:

```
  sku        date    A      B
0   A  2022-08-29  100    NaN
1   A  2022-08-30  110  100.0
2   B  2022-08-29    0  110.0
3   B  2022-08-30  210    0.0
4   C  2022-08-29  300  210.0
5   C  2022-08-30  310  300.0
```